# How to prove first order non-linear recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction, recursion

I have a non-linear recurrence relation I derived from observing the first few terms, and wish to prove by induction it is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

$$P_n = P_{n-1}(P_{n-1} + 1)$$

For reference, $P_n$ denotes the total number of paths from a source vertex to a destination vertex in a directed graph (Hanoi graph). The source vertex in this case is the very top named 111, and destination the bottom right 333.

[image: Hanoi graph]

I understand it is difficult to solve non linear recurrences, does anyone know of a way I can prove this formula, either through solving or otherwise?

Comment: @Prometheus could you explain what you mean? That does not appear like a second-order recurrence relationship as it only uses one previous term. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah mb, I didn't see correctly

Comment: This is the sequence https://oeis.org/A007018 in the OEIS. There is no known closed form.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek what is your source that there is no closed form

Comment: @TinaYu I said merely that on the OEIS (see link) there is no *known* closed form.